# Why closed tabs re-opened automatically in visual studio 2017 communitity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I found the visual studio like save a snapshot of my opened file tabs setting. When I close some tabs, closed and re-open visual studio, those closed tabs are re-opened automatically (unless I delete the file). It's a pain as I don't need those tabs. Vice versa, some newly opened tabs will be closed...Anyone knows what is going on? I am using vs 2017 community.

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` directory inside the directory with the `.sln` file (you may have to show hidden files to see it).  That will reset all your user-level UI settings for the project.  It sounds like something may have gotten corrupted.  Visual Studio will recreate it next time you open the solution.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, it works now, thanks!